# Javascript remove Ampersand "&amp;" from the url and go the new url at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have seen examples on how to remove &amp and replace with & in the url in Javascript. However, I don't get how to replace characters in the url and then use the url at the same time. Javascript is not my strong suit so please forgive me. I have tried the following below and it took me to http://flowline/&amp. What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve my end result in Javascript?

```
   window.location = '/index.php?name=raider&amp;do=see&amp;ext=account&amp;action=processed';
   window.location.replace('&amp;','&')
```

Comment: str.replace(/&amp;/g,"&");

Comment: Why is `&amp;` there in the first place? Seem like fixing that would be the smartest thing to do.

Comment: You are correct but it's a workaround with some protections in my script. I rather not disable the protections to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a variable first:

```
let url = '/index.php?name=raider&amp;do=see&amp;ext=account&amp;action=processed';
window.location = url.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
```

Comment: The solution presented went to the correct url but it still had &amp; and not "&'.

Comment: What still had "&amp;"? The address bar in the browser?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes the address bar in the browser

Comment: I think _location_ needs a fully-qualified URL. Try that and it should work as expected.